# Reproduce code documentation style of

Tags: listings

I would like to reproduce the way in which the refman team put their documentation [image]

In my case, I want something like

```
function explanation
         code snippet
```

My (ugly) attempt is using minipage and listings

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\textwidth}
  \texttt{functionname}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\textwidth}
Explanation
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily, language=C, numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny\color{black}]
for i in 1:3
    @show i
end
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Thanks in advance for your patience and attention.

Comment: You should look at the documentation `.tex` file for more insight...

Comment: Hi, @Werner I downloaded all the files in the directory () and only in the file refman.dtx is `% \begin{macro}{\@ptsize}
%    This control sequence is used to store the second digit of the
%    pointsize we are typesetting in. So, normally, its value is one
%    of 0, 1 or 2.
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<*refart|refrep>
\newcommand\@ptsize{}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}`
For me, this is incomprehensible, so I am asking for better guidance than this obscure document.

Comment: the `refman` is almost certainly written using the conventions of the `doc` package.  to understand how this works, take a look at the user documentation -- `texdoc doc`.  it will be most helpful if you look at the output side by side with the input in the file `doc.tex`.  section 3.3, "macros for the 'documentation parts" " should be helpful.  it's the format of the input file that you want to pay attention to.  processing such a `.tex` file with latex produces the user documentation; processing the `.ins` file (which uses `docstrip`) produces the .sty file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output you show is from processing [`refman.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/refman/refman.dtx) using [`docstrip`](http://ctan.org/pkg/docstrip). It processes a file containing documentation and code for possible distribution into various outputs (like `.sty` and `.cls` files). The documentation contains regular text, as well as `macro` and `macrocode` environments (among other things) to describe macros together with their code. These environments are defined inside the [`doc` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/doc).

The following is a toned-down version of how to use it in a regular document:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{doc}

\CodelineNumbered

\begin{document}

\begin{macro}{\@ptsize}
  This control sequence is used to store the second digit of the
  pointsize we are typesetting in. So, normally, its value is one
  of 0, 1 or 2.
\begin{macrocode}
<*refart|refrep>
\newcommand\@ptsize{}
%    \end{macrocode}
\end{macro}

\end{document}
```

Note how the `macrocode` environment is required to end with the clause

```
%    \end{macrocode}
```

(that is, `%` followed by four spaces      followed by `\end{macrocode}`). Since it's typically used in `docstrip`-specific code documentation it's not an issue. However, using it inside a regular document requires this strange ending.

---

Perhaps you can try the following interface, similar to what is provided by the [`doc` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/doc)'s interface for `macro`s and `macrocode`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\newenvironment{macro}[1]
  {\par\noindent
   \makebox[0pt][r]{\texttt{#1}\quad}%
   \ignorespaces}
  {}
\lstnewenvironment{macrocode}[1][]
  {\lstset{
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    language = C,
    numbers = left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    #1}}
  {}

\begin{document}

\begin{macro}{functionname}
Explanation
\begin{macrocode}
for i in 1:3
    @show i
end
\end{macrocode}
\end{macro}

\end{document}
```

The `functionname` is set inside the margin, together with the line numbering of the function. If your `functionname` could contain bizarre (reserved) characters like `_` or `$`, one would have to do a bit more work.